# Add External Internet Route to Existing (VPN based) Network

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

The situation is as follows.  A remote site is connected via VPN router to the "mothership."  They now have their own high speed internet connection that they need to use for external internet tasks such as uploads/downloads because its much faster than the VPN connection.

They want to add this capability without disrupting the existing network (all telephones go through the VPN for example).  The VPN connection is thru a lower end Netgear VPN router that does have a static route capability.

I have been doing a little reading and my hypothesis is that I can put the new internet router (FIOS) on the existing subnet and then define a static route to route any traffic with a non-subnet address out through the FIOS router as the gateway.  Everything else stays as is.

Could somebody comment on whether this strategy makes sense?  At least give me some good keywords to search for?

(sorry only a junior networking guy...not a guru)